# Function with an argument without a return value not working properly on turbo c

Tags: c, function, arguments, turbo-c

I have this program, which some of you may have seen from my past questions. This is about converting decimal to binary and octal, binary to decimal and octal, and octal to decimal and binary.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void MainMenu();
int UserInput();
unsigned long Dec2BinOct(unsigned long n);
void Dec2BinOct2(unsigned long n);
unsigned long Bin2DecOct(unsigned long n);
unsigned long Bin2DecOct2(unsigned long dec);
unsigned long Oct2BinDec(unsigned long n, int base, int base2);

unsigned long main()
{
    char choice;
    unsigned long n;


   clrscr();
   do{
    unsigned long bin, o, dec;

    MainMenu();
    printf("enter your choice: ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    printf("\n");
    switch(choice){

        case 'A':
        case 'a':

            printf("Conversion: Decimal to binary and octal.\n");
            printf("Enter number: ");
        n = UserInput();

            o   = Dec2BinOct(n);

            printf("%lu in Decimal is ", n);
        Dec2BinOct2(n);
        printf(" in Binary Form.\n");
            printf("%lu in Decimal is %lu in Octal Form.\n\n", n, o);

        break;

        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            printf("Conversion: Binary to decimal and octal.\n");
            printf("Enter number: ");
            n = UserInput();


            dec = Bin2DecOct(n);
            o = Bin2DecOct2(dec);

            printf("%lu in Binary is %lu in Decimal Form.\n", n, dec);
            printf("%lu in Binary is %lu in Octal Form.\n\n", n, o);

        break;

        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            printf("Conversion: Octal to decimal and binary.\n");
            printf("Enter number: ");
            n = UserInput();


            bin = Oct2BinDec(n, 2, 10);
            dec = Oct2BinDec(n, 10, 8);

            printf("%lu in Octal is %lu in Binary Form\n", n, bin);
            printf("%lu in Octal is %lu in Decimal Form.\n\n", n, dec);


        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            printf("Exit.\n\n");
        break;

        default:
          break;

    }

   }while(choice != 'd'&& choice != 'D');
    getch();
}

void MainMenu()
{
    printf("Choices:\na. Decimal to binary and octal\nb. Binary to decimal and octal\nc. Octal to decimal and binary\nd. Exit.\n\n");
}

int UserInput(n)
{
    scanf("%lu", &n);
    return n;
}

unsigned long Dec2BinOct(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long place=1, bin=0;
    for(; n != 0; place *= 10)
                    {

                        bin   += n % 8 * place;
                        n     = n / 8;
                    }
    return(bin);
}

void  Dec2BinOct2(unsigned long n)
{
    int x=25, y=24;
    unsigned long p=n;
    while(x)
    {
        if(n<pow(2, x))
        {
            if(n>=pow(2, y))
            {
                printf("1");
                n-=pow(2, y);
            }
            else if(n<p)
            {
                printf("0");
            }
        }

        x--;
        y--;
    }

}

unsigned long Bin2DecOct(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long ans=1, dec=0;
    for(; n != 0; ans *= 2)
                    {
                        
                        dec = dec + n % 10 * ans; 
                        n   = n / 10;
                    }
    return(dec);
}

unsigned long Bin2DecOct2(unsigned long dec)
{
    unsigned long o=0, place=1;
    while (dec != 0)
                    {
                        o     = o + (dec % 8) * place;
                        dec   = dec / 8;
                        place = place * 10;
                    }
    return(o);
}

unsigned long Oct2BinDec(unsigned long n, int base, int base2)
{
    unsigned long bin=0, place=1;
    for(; n != 0; place *= base2)  
                    {      
                        bin   += n % base * place;
                        n     = n / base;  
                    }
    return(bin);
}
```

But when I chose option letter a/A, the function Dec2BinOct2(n) won't do its thing. It won't print.

```
Choices:
a. Decimal to binary and octal
b. Binary to decimal and octal
c. Octal to decimal and binary
d. Exit.

enter your choice: >>>a

Conversion: Decimal to binary and octal.
Enter number: >>>123
123 in Decimal is in Binary Form.
123 in Decimal is 173 in Octal Form.
```

But in dcoder, it works just fine. I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Hi. You could start to isolate the problem with an [MCVE]: try just to have `Dec2BinOct2` called by a `main` function. Did that works?

Comment: `int UserInput(n) { scanf("%lu", &n); return n; }` - what type is `n` here? Is `%lu` correct for that type? Perhaps you should make it `unsigned long UserInput() { unsigned long n; sscanf("%lu", &n); return n; }` instead? You won't be able to catch `scanf` problems this way though.

Comment: `unsigned long main()` eeeh? Now why are you using a completely outdated compiler for? If Turbo C refers to the old MS DOS compiler, it's from 1989. Borland released several newer versions during the 1990s, until everyone stopped using DOS completely, around year 2000. It's year 2021 now, your compiler upgrade is long overdue.

Comment: BTW: don't use tools that are older than you. TurboC is an antique piece of software that shouldn't be used any more. There are better alternatives.

Comment: Octal and binary representation are textual representations of integer values. They are text, i.e. strings. What makes you using `unsigned long` for text? Your compiler will not provide any data type that can hold enough digits to store a 32bit value in binary representation.

Comment: @Jabberwocky this is what our teacher wants us to use ToT

Comment: @Jabberwocky "BTW: don't use tools that are older than you" --> Ha ha, looks like I'm good for every C compiler.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica me to BTW. But at least we old guys know that we shouldn't use antiquated tools ;-)

Comment: @Jabberwocky "we shouldn't use antiquated tools" --> sometimes, the choices we have are not as wide as others have.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer now.

```
#include<math.h>
```

That's why the pow function isn't working and nothing is printing. Anyways, thank you guys!

Comment: Note: `pow(2, x)` is a weak approach with this integer code.  Consider  `1ull << x` instead.